# cakephp: delayed flash messages

Tags: cakephp

Is there any functionality that allow me do something like flash messages in `cakephp`? I don't want to use session, because it shows flash message on the next page.

For example:
user type link with mistake `mysite?action=mistake` and i want to check in controller if there isnt mistakes like this so i have array with some actions which are allowed and i check if `$this->params['url']['action']` is there. If it isn't i want to show error to user , but this error shows only on second page (or if i reload). How can i avoid this?

Comment: You usually don't pass the flashmessages via url querystrings but internally using the session. That is cleaner and can easier be handled without conflicting with other querystrings and also works with multiple types of flashs as well as multiple messages per type etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is just a `div` with a concrete style. Something like:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="error-message">Error</div>
```

What you could do is check with Javascript whatever you want to check and if it is not as expected, append the error `div` wherever you want.

That's what I have dont in some forms to show the error in real time.

If you want something more elaborate you could try this:
http://www.alfbd.com/cakephp-ajax-form-validation-with-jquery-and-jsonview/